# Maven project dependency "could not find artifact"

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I have 2 maven projects.  Project A and Project B.  Project B is dependent on Project A but not the other way around.

In my project B pom I have this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com</groupId>
        <artifactId>ProjectA</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

When i try to package the project it fails with this error:

```
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ProjectB: Could not resolve    dependencies for project com:ProjectB:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find  artifact com:ProjectA:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project ProjectB: Could not resolve dependencies for project com:ProjectB:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com:ProjectA:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

So it can't find my ProjectA pom.  Do I need to put it in my project?  Where should it be located in my file structure.

For what it's worth, I am using intelliJ IDE.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: When i run install on projectA I get this error:

```
The packaging for this project did not assign a file to the build artifact
```

EDIT2 - Adding ProjectA pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>edu</groupId>
<artifactId>ProjectA</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>ProjectA</name>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install-jar-lib</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-package</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <copy file="${basedir}/src/main/webapp/META-INF/context-${app.environment}.xml"
                                  tofile="${basedir}/src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml" />
                            <copy file="${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web-${app.environment}.xml"
                                  tofile="${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml" />
                            <copy file="${basedir}/src/main/resources/log4j-${app.environment}.xml"
                                  tofile="${basedir}/src/main/resources/log4j.xml" />
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <copy file="${project.build.directory}/classes/log4j-${app.environment}.xml"
                                  tofile="${project.build.directory}/classes/log4j.xml" />
                            <delete>
                                <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/classes" includes="**/*-local.*"/>
                                <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/classes" includes="**/*-test.*"/>
                                <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/classes" includes="**/*-prod.*"/>
                            </delete>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>package</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <delete file="${basedir}/src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml" />
                            <delete file="${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml" />
                            <tstamp>
                                <format property="last.timestamp" pattern="yyyyMMddHHmmss"/>
                            </tstamp>
                            <property name="build.time" value="${last.timestamp}" />
                        </target>
                        <exportAntProperties>true</exportAntProperties>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <!--<webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/WEB-INF/lib</directory>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF/lib</targetPath>
                        <filtering>false</filtering>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.jar</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>-->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.coderplus.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>copy-rename-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>rename-file</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>rename</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceFile>${project.build.directory}/${artifactId}-${version}.war</sourceFile>
                        <destinationFile>${project.build.directory}/ProjectA##${build.time}.war</destinationFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to install `ProjectA` in your local Maven repo (or otherwise make it available in whatever remote repositories your pom.xml or settings.xml point at). For example:

```
cd whereever/projectA/lives
mvn clean install
```

This will write `com/ProjectA/ProjectA.pom` to your local Maven repo and when you do this ...

```
cd wherever/projectB/lives
mvn clean install
```

... Maven will resolve `ProjectA.pom` from that location.

Note: the dependency you have declared on `ProjectA`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProjectA</artifactId>
    <type>pom</type>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

... will transitively add all dependencies declared in `com:ProjectA` to `ProjectB`'s POM, is that definitely your intention? This only makes sense if `ProjectA` is packaged as a POM, if it is packaged as a JAR then you need to update the dependency declaration in ProjectB to remove this line: `<type>pom</type>`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  So I am a little unclear on the install thing and get an error whenever I run that maven command.  Also for your last question, I am building a war artifact, so I removed the <type>pom</type> part

Comment: You wrote: "I am a little unclear on the install thing and get an error whenever I run that maven command", if you want help with that please update your question to describe exactly what that error. Re this comment: "I am building a war artifact, so I removed the <type>pom</type>" if Project A is a WAR then you cannot declare a dependency on it, you **depend** on a JAR, you **run** a WAR.

Comment: Gotcha, I believe I do need to depend on the pom because the project isn't being built as a jar.  I edited my original post to describe the error I was getting when running install command on projectA

Comment: Re your latest update (_The packaging for this project did not assign a file to the build artifact_), anyone attempting to diagnose that for you would need to see the ProjectA POM . It's likely that ProjectA is not producing any artifact hence there is nothing to **install**. Feels like this might be one question becoming several sub questions :)

Comment: Yeah it definitely is turning into that.  I will post my pom, but if the scope of the questions gets too big, I might just need to do some research before posting anymore